# How to exclude condition from if statement in Java

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I'm trying so search a number of lines of a text file using a user input (string 'question'), but I need to exclude some common terms as they bring up erroneous results as well as correct ones.

```
 try {
            readName file = new readName(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();//OPEN  KNOWLEDGE BASE

            //SEARCH EACH ENTRY IN KNOWLEDGE BASE
            for (int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i = i + 1) {
                String delims = "[ ]+";//SPLIT ITEMS INTO TOKENS
                //CREATE ARRAY OF TOKENS 
                String[] tokens = aryLines[i].split(delims);

                //SEARCH THROUGH TOKENS
                for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j = j + 1){
                    //MATCH QUESTIONS AGAINST TOKENS AND EXCLUSIONS
                    if (question.matches("(.*)" + tokens[j] + "(.*)")) {
                        System.out.println(aryLines[i]);

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

I have tried putting in

```
 if (question.matches("(.*)" + tokens[j] + "(.*)") 
         && !question.matches(*excluded word*))
```

But in that case, it produces no result when the search question is entered. Both versions work correctly when the excluded term in omitted from the search question.

I have hunted around on here and in other places, but nothing's working for me so far. Any help much appreciated!

This is a sample of my knowledge base

```
Dogs have tails 
Donkeys have no humps
```

If I search for `no tails`, it outputs both lines, but I would like to force it to exclude `no` from the search so that it only returns `Dogs have tails`

Comment: could you provide a sample of what is in your KNOWLEDGE BASE, a few sample data. It will help to understand your problem.

Comment: At the moment, just for the sake of testing it is 2 lines as follows: Dogs have tails, Donkeys have no humps. If I search for no tails, it outputs both lines, but I would like to force it to exclude 'no' from the search so that it only returns 'Dogs have tails'. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tidying up ;)

Comment: What your code is doing is just iterating over the lines, then over the tokens you created, but the token you provide on your code was `[ ]+` which means every blank spaces. So for the first line you will have: `[0]Dogs [1]have [2]tails` as tokens and for the second line you will have `[0]Donkeys [1]have [2]no [3]humps` when you search for `no tails` it willnot match anything since it is matching your question with every token and none of then is your question.

Comment: So maybe if I split 'question' into tokens as well then, and then compare them with 'tokens'?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `if ( question.indexOf(tokens[j])!=-1 )` but I'm really not sure. this will say if that token is inside my question do something

Comment: And "I'm not sure" because i couldn't be abble to understand what you want for sure.

Comment: Is there any chance you could make your requirements clearer? Currently, it seems that I am not alone in failing to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK so the a JOptionPane asks you what question you want to ask. You enter your question, but I want to eliminate common words from the question, like 'no', 'a', 'it', etc when the system reads in your question. The intention is that the user can ask a question in legible english which won't churn out lots of irrelevant results.

Comment: So for example if someone were to ask the question "How many turnips can a farmer grow in a year?" the system will only look for the words 'turnips', 'farmer', 'grow' and 'year.

Comment: In the above example, I would  use an array for the excluded words, but for now I can happily just use any word (hence why I chose 'no' earlier) as a placeholder while (read if) I get this working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
//THIS IS AN EXAMPLE KNOWLEDGE BASE
String[] aryLines = {"Dogs have tails","Donkeys have no humps"};

//THIS IS THE QUESTION SUPPLIED BY POSTER
String question = "no tails";

//IT SEEMS THAT POSTER WANTS TO EXCLUDE CERTAIN WORDS FROM THE SEARCH
String exclude = "no";

//REMOVE ALL OCCURRENCES OF THE EXCLUDE STRING IN QUESTION
question = question.replaceAll(exclude, "");

//FOR EACH TOKEN (FROM KNOWLEDGE BASE)
for(String token : aryLines) {
    //MATCH QUESTION AGAINST TOKENS
    if (token.matches("(.*)" + question + "(.*)")) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

In this example, I remove all occurrences of the excluded string in the question. I then compare the tokens to the regex: `.*<question>.*`.

Since the excluded strings have been removed prior to the comparison, they will no longer affect the outcome of the match, as the code will compare `Dogs have tails` and `Donkeys have no humps` to `.*tails.*`.

Comment: Cunning, I like it. I'll give it a whirl and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, worked perfectly, many thanks. Can't believe I didn't think of that, makes sense! Greatly appreciated @Daemon and Jorge